# How to set language globally for moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I get for example: 1day ago. What I need is to set for different language, for example for `de`. Any suggestion how can I do that?

```
moment(Date.now()).fromNow()
```

I tried this:

```
<script>
    var moment = moment();
    moment.locale('de');
</script>
```

but get an error:

> moment is not a function

Comment: See [Changing locale globally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) note that you have to import locale data (e.g, [`moment-with-locales.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js) )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See official docs on how [changing locale globally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/).

Note that you have to import locale data (e.g. [`moment-with-locales.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js))

Here a working example:

```js
moment.locale('de');
console.log(moment(Date.now()).fromNow()); //vor ein paar Sekunden
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use only data for a given locale (e.g. `de`):

```js
moment.locale('de');
console.log(moment(Date.now()).fromNow()); //vor ein paar Sekunden
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/de.js"></script>
```

Moreover you are redefining moment in  your code, that is incorrect

```
var moment = moment();
```

Comment: For typescript or nodejs app you should use a `require('moment/locale/es')` before using `moment.locale('es')` for example

Answer (score 17):

EDIT: In the current version of moment.js this solution still works but it will output a message to the console that states you should use a new method called updateLocale. So the new solution should look like:

**Updated solution**

```
import moment from 'moment';
import localization from 'moment/locale/fr';

moment.updateLocale('fr', localization);
```

**Previous Solution**

You can change moment locale globally like that:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import localization from 'moment/locale/fr';

moment.locale('fr', localization);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: this is the only way I have been able to get the latest release to work on react native, installing moment via yarn

Answer (score 2):

To build onto the answer by Gapur, how I got it to work (React native) was like this,

```
... other imports
import moment from "moment";
import russianLocale from "moment/locale/ru";
import englishLocale from "moment/locale/en-gb";
import chineseLocale from "moment/locale/zh-cn";

const Component = ({ ...props, language }) => {
  moment.locale(language);

... logic

// wherever 'moment' is used, it's displayed in 
// the language that is indicated by the language prop

... other logic
```

moment version 2.24.0

Answer (score 1):

for example I want to use 'fa' locale

```
import moment from 'moment'
import fa from 'moment/locale/fa'

moment.locale('fa', fa)
```