# Localization javascript moment not working

Tags: javascript

I have this js to display the day, date + time. But it's in English and does not translate into Dutch (nl)

```
moment.locale("nl");
var date_and_time = moment(countDownDate).format("dddd, DD MMMM YYYY, HH:mm uur");
```

How can I make it display in Dutch?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is similar to yours and perhaps it can help you also. See link below:

[[How to set language globally for moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595585/how-to-set-language-globally-for-moment-js?rq=1][1])

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seemed to work. Until I discovered I included an old moment.js library without local support.

I changed it to **moment-with-locales.min.js** and now it works.

Thanks for the suggestions, which helped me dive further into this.